# Можно ли программами/драйверами для MySQL подключаться к MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, ide, mariadb

Читаю, что эти две базы данных одного автора и имеют много одинакового. MariaDB не использовал. Можно ли программами/драйверами для MySQL подключаться к MariaDB ? или у них совершенно разные протоколы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/:

> All client APIs, protocols and structs are identical.
>
> All MySQL connectors (PHP, Perl, Python, Java, .NET, MyODBC, Ruby, MySQL C connector etc) work unchanged with MariaDB.

Автор обещает полную совместимость. Пробуйте.